# How can I write to windows event log from ASP.NET4.0 Web application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Our IIS is Ver10.0 on WindowsServer2016 Standard.
My trial code is the bellow. Of course we are getting Page transition, but we can't see any letters from that page on windows eventlog.

```
Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim sourceName As String = "MySource"
    If Not System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(sourceName) Then
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceName, "")
    End If

    Dim myData() As Byte = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(sourceName, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, 1, 1000, myData)

    Server.Transfer("Menu2.aspx")
End Sub
```

Could someone tell me how to get the results?
Am I make a mistaking where I check? I have been checking windows event viewer for it.

Thanks

Comment: Could be a little off here, but I suspect this will come down to the level of permissions you've given the app pool (Assuming IIS here).  You may need to run the application pool with higher privileges to enable access to the windows environment

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I can't help changing the way, can I? I don't know the other way to solve it so far ,though.

Comment: Not really,  assuming I’m on the right track myself, The nature of web apps is to be “sandboxed” from the workings of the host by default.